# Inserting into a Rosbag

Tags: python, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to add to a message to a rosbag at the beginning? I know you can append to a rosbag, but I want the message at the beginning.

Inserting all the other messages in afterward screws up the timing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33318/inserting-into-a-rosbag/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think rosbag Cookbook can do what you want. http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook

By section 1.2 of that link you do the following

```
import rosbag

with rosbag.Bag('input.bag', 'a') as bag:
    from std_msgs.msg import String
    metadata = String(data='my metadata')

    for _, _, t in bag.read_messages():
        break
    bag.write('/metadata', metadata, t - roslib.rostime.Duration(0, 1))
```

Of course this does require post processing the data which may not be desirable.

---

Originally posted by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) with karma: 328 on 2012-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2016-08-29**:
`bag.write` appends to a bagfile, but your code gets the emit time of the first message and substracts one usec, so that the metadata is the first message being emitted which results in a mess. To get a proper bag you'll need to add `subprocess.Popen(['rosbag', 'fix', 'input.bag', 'output.bag'])`